# How to import a Stata file into SAS 9.0?

Tags: import, sas, stata

I have already converted the Stata file into the old version `saveold`

The following doesn't work for my SAS 9.0

```
proc import datafile="d:\hsb.dta" out=mydata dbms = dta replace;
run;
proc print data=mydata;
run;
```

`ERROR: DBMS type DTA not valid for import.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS did not add support to importing Stata files until version 9.1.3 (see [this tech support note](http://support.sas.com/kb/18/199.html)).  You will need to either upgrade your version of SAS to 9.1.3 or newer (current version is 9.3 with 9.4 in the process of being released), or export it from Stata in some format such as a text file as Nick suggests.

Assuming your version of SAS is validly licensed, you should easily be able to upgrade simply by contacting your SAS site representative.  There's very little reason to use 9.0; it was very quickly replaced by 9.1.3 due to several significant issues with 9.0.

You also need to have licensed SAS/ACCESS to PC File Formats.  This is an optional license with Base SAS.  You can verify your license by running:

```
PROC SETINIT; RUN;
```

If you see an entry for

```
SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files
```

then you have it licensed.  If not then you need to contact your site rep or consider an alternative to direct import.

Answer (score 2):

People on both sides need more exact detail here.

In Stata, the `saveold` command `save`s the dataset in memory, but so that the previous version of Stata can read it. Sometimes, but not always, earlier versions of Stata can read it too. Hence from http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dsave.pdf you can learn that `saveold` in Stata 13 will produce a dataset that can be read by Stata 12, and also Stata 11. The compatibility, as in this example, can be more than one version earlier, because StataCorp does not change the storage format of datasets every time it produces a new version of Stata. So, `saveold` in version n assures readability in version n - 1 and may imply readability in version n - 2 or earlier.

So, from the Stata point of view you need to be exact about which version of Stata you were using.

The question remains for SAS people what precisely can SAS 9.0 read. One guess is that SAS 9.0 can read Stata `.dta` files, just not the version that the poster has saved. However, the answer may be just issuing the wrong command in SAS, and I hope that someone can address that.

A broad alternative remains to export your data from Stata as some kind of text file.

Answer (score 2):

A sure fire way to export any kind of Stata data file would be to save it as a csv file via the following command in Stata:

```
outsheet using "directory/foo.csv", comma replace
```

SAS should have no problem importing a csv file.